# How do you generate an animated square wave from binary number for the respective decimal number using for loop

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am using the following codes to generate the square wave format [Eg: from 0 till 5] using for loop. I am able to print the respective binary values but not able to plot the square wave dynamically.In addition to this I am not able to dynamically resize the x axis in the plot window. I could not find any suitable code at Matplotlib animation section. Could any one help me in this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

limit=int(raw_input('Enter the value of limit:'))

for x in range(0,limit):
    y=bin(x)[2:]
    data = [int(i) for i in y]
    print data
    xs = np.repeat(range(len(data)),2)
    ys = np.repeat(data, 2)
    xs = xs[1:]
    ys = ys[:-1]
    plt.plot(xs, ys)
    plt.xlim(0,len(data)+0.5)
    plt.ylim(-2, 2)
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
    #plt.hold(True)
    #plt.pause(0.5)
    plt.clf()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question as stated is pretty vague so I'm going to I'm going to go out on a limb and assume that what you want is to plot a series of equal length binary codes using the same figure with some delay in between.

So, two problems here:

1. Generating the appropriate binary codes
2. Plotting those codes successively

## 1. Generating the appropriate binary codes

From what I can reasonably guess, you want to plot binary codes of the same length. So you'll have to zero pad your codes so they are the same length. One way to do this is with python's built in zfill function.

e.g.

`bin(1).zfill(4)`

This also brings light to the fact that you will have to know the length of the largest binary string you want to plot if you want to keep the x-axis range constant. Since it's not clear if you even want constant length strings I'll just leave it at this.

## 2. Plotting those codes successively

There are a couple different ways to create animations in matplotlib. I find manually updating data is a little bit more flexible and less buggy than the animations API currently is so I will be doing that here. I've also cut down some parts of the code that were not clear to me.

Here's a simple a implementation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Enable interactive plotting
plt.ion()

# Create a figure and axis for plotting on
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Add the line 'artist' to the plotting axis
# use 'steps' to plot binary codes
line = plt.Line2D((),(),drawstyle='steps-pre')
ax.add_line(line)

# Apply any static formatting to the axis
ax.grid()
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
# ...

try:
    limit = int(raw_input('Enter the value of limit:'))
    codelength = int(np.ceil(np.log2(limit)))+1 # see note*
    ax.set_xlim(0,codelength)
    for x in range(0,limit):
        # create your fake data
        y = bin(x)[2:].zfill(codelength)
        data = [int(i) for i in y]
        print data
        xs = range(len(data))

        line.set_data(xs,data)  # Update line data
        fig.canvas.draw()       # Ask to redraw the figure

        # Do a *required* pause to allow figure to redraw
        plt.pause(2)            # delay in seconds between frames
except KeyboardInterrupt:   # allow user to escape with Ctrl+c
    pass
finally:                    # Always clean up!
    plt.close(fig)
    plt.ioff()
    del ax,fig
```

## Result

[image: binary code plot]

*Note: I padded the binary codes by an extra zero to get the plot to look right.

Comment: @ toes : Working fine.There is a key point to learn from your code and that is dynamic update of x axis V/S manual update of  x axis.