# How to plot square function with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing

I have an list of values that alternate between 0 and 1, eg [0,1,0,1,0] and I want to graph them so they appear as a square wave using matplotlib for python. I have this so far:

```
input_amp = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
plt.plot(input_amp, marker='d', color='blue')
plt.title("Waveform")
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.savefig("waveform.png")
plt.show()
```

This gives me an output like this [image: this]:

How do I make it so instead of going on an angle between the points the line stays flat?

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567520/how-do-you-generate-an-animated-square-wave-from-binary-number-for-the-respectiv) but it deals more with an animation and not just plotting the function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The relevant bit from that post you reference is the `drawstyle`:

```
 plt.plot(input_amp, marker='d', color='blue', drawstyle='steps-pre')
```

Comment: drawstyle='steps-post' is more commonly used.

Answer (score -1):

"Elementary, Watson!"

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import numpy as np

# Sampling rate 1000 hz / second
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 100, endpoint=True)

# Plot the square wave signal
plot.plot(t, signal.square(2 * np.pi * 1 * t))

# A title for the square wave plot
plot.title('1Hz square wave sampled at 100 Hz /second')

# x axis label for the square wave plot
plot.xlabel('Time')
    
# y axis label for the square wave plot
plot.ylabel('Amplitude')
plot.grid(True, which='both')

# Provide x axis and line color
plot.axhline(y=0, color='k')

# Set the max and min values for y axis
plot.ylim(-1.2, 1.2)

# Display the square wave
plot.show()
```

[image: square wave]

Comment: The amplitude of this waveform is from 1 to -1. Can you please show how can extend this wave from 0 to 2 instead?